# Write generated images to relative location in webapp and in unit test

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, junit

Here's my scenario: I'm writing a rest endpoint that returns resized .png images dynamically.  On my server, I have a lot of disk space and a slow processor.  97% of the generated images are going to be from about 10 commonly requested sizes.  What this means is that I'm going to see a performance benefit if I cache generated the generated images on disk and serve them on request, vs just generating on the fly every time.

My question is this: How can I specify a directory for these images to be generated to?  Requirements:

1. When running in the webapp, the generated images directory must be relative to somewhere in the webapp.  Perhaps something like `/WEB-INF/generated-images`
2. I must also be able to unit-test my image generator outside of a webapp, and specify a generated images directory relative to the location where the unit test is running.  An acceptable directory in my maven project would be something like `${project}/target/generated-images`.

I'm using Spring, in both the webapp and in the JUnit test.  Specifying an absolute directory path is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: How often do you need to generate these images?

Comment: Obviously not a direct answer to your question, but given the tags you used perhaps it would save you some time to look at [existing caching solutions](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/14/cache-abstraction-jcache-jsr-107-annotations-support) before your roll your own?